# Outer div has click function but inner div cannot

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I don't know how to effectively title the problem but here's the situation.

I have an overlay that is a login window that pops up on a page that a non logged in user cannot access.  Since the user cannot access that page I can't have the normal functioning where if you click outside the pop up it just removes itself from the page.  So what I have is a re-direct to the sign up page.  However since this click function is on the outer div,  on the login form inside this div when the user goes to enter the credentials it re-directs.

So I need to not allow it on the form.

So I did this:

```
$('#logform').click(false);
```

which works,  but now the button to login wont work?

Example:

```
    <div id="maindiv>
    <form id="logform">
    <input type="text" name="exampleinput">
    <button type="submit" id="loginbutton">
    </form>
    </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.maindiv').show();
        $('.maindiv').click(function(){
            window.location.href='/users/account-info';
        });
    
        $('#logform').click(false);
    
    });


</script>
```

So how can I disable the href click function for the form but also allow the login button to function correctly?

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow. If you put your code and some CSS in a snippet we can see it.

Comment: I don't know how to do that as I don't use stack much.  Also the actual code is like a 100 line form.   Basically think of it like this:  if the outer div has some action like a click event on it, how can I make it so the inner div is not affected by this event?

Comment: Click the button in the editor and follow the cues. Be sure to use the Tidy button.

Comment: I agree with the others that your workflow here is confusing. I think you should rethink this process. If I arrive at your page and I'm not logged in, why not just automatically redirect me to the login page instead of making me click somewhere?

Comment: ha well I wish my boss had our logic @ScottMarcus

Comment: he's paying me and this is what he wants.

Comment: Ok, so please explain this more clearly. I'm not logged in and I arrive at this page. The `maindiv` modal comes up, which includes a `form`. Should I be able to fill in that form and click submit as a non-logged in user? And, how would this page work if was already logged in when I arrived at this page?

Comment: Great questions.  If you're logged in the pop up login window never comes up so it's not an issue.  Right now it pops up and anywhere I click (since the href is on the outer div) it automatically goes to this account-info page.  What I want is it to function like this everywhere except the login form.  Because  now the second I click on the username input to input my username the click function triggers and then the re-direct happens

Comment: So as listed in the question I did this: $('#logform').click(false);   which works but now disables the login button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is determine what the element was that the event was triggered on, which can be determined by looking at the `event` object's `.target` property. The `event` object is automatically passed to all DOM event handlers that are registered using a JQuery binding or the vanilla `.addEventListener()` method.

```css
#maindiv {
 background-color:grey;
 width:100vw; height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">
  <form id="logform">
    <input type="text" name="exampleinput">
    <button type="submit" id="loginbutton">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Set the event handler up so that it recieves the event reference
    $('#maindiv').on("click", function(event){
      // Determine where the event was triggered
      // If the click was on the div...
      if(event.target === this){
        location.href='http://www.example.com';  // Redirect
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is the solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Can you change your code? Or is it auto-generated? If you can change your code I highly recommend you place the form into another div outside of your main div, like so:

```
    <div id="maindiv">
    </div>
    <div id="formdiv">
        <form id="logform">
            <input type="text" name="exampleinput">
            <button type="submit" id="loginbutton">
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.maindiv').show();
        $('.maindiv').click(function(){
            window.location.href='/users/account-info';
        });
    
        $('#logform').click(false);
    
    });


</script>
```

This would allow you to, with a bit of CSS click the form without clicking the surrounding div. Assuming you want to freeze your screen so that the user can't scroll, use `position: absolute;` in your CSS file. If you want to let your user scroll but lack the ability to interact with anything, use `position: fixed;`. This allows your form to be on top of or under other elements. Then, set `z-index` to anything greater than the `z-index` of your background div, or, if you haven't set it yet, write `z-index: 2;`. The higher `z-index` when two elements are in the same place is the one that ends up over the other element. This means that your form is on top of(or in front of, they mean the same anyway) your background div, meaning when you click it, you don't actually click the div around it. This allows you to get rid of `$('#logform').click(false);`

Hope this answer helps you!